# Does ASP.NET MVC need to be installed on my production web server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My IT folks don't like to install software on their precious servers unless they must.  To that extent, does the server that serves my ASP.NET MVC application need to have the MVC 1.0 Framework on it in addition to .NET 3.5 sp 1 Framework?

Comment: FYI I think that the MVC projects are created like this by default because they place the MVC DLL in the bin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope. You can deploy the System.Web.Mvc.dll to your application's bin directory if MVC has not been installed on the server. The only requirement is that the server have .NET Framework 3.5 (preferably with SP1)

Comment: If the server doesn't have SP1, you'll need to bin deploy System.Web.Abstractions, too.

Comment: Yep, in addition to System.Web.Routing.dll I believe.

Answer (score 6):

[Phil Haack put together an article on bin deploying MVC apps here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).  It mentions the ASP.Net MVC beta drop, but it still works just fine (given the caveat that .Net 3.5's installed).